# CSR list animation removes formatting, any way to keep both?

Tags: list-view, client-side-rendering

I have been struggling with keeping the formatting on my list. When i filter, search, or sort, my formatting is removed from the affected rows. After some googling i found a solution; removing the animation from the list.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.
                      RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
})();

function postRenderHandler(ctx)
{
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var row = document.getElementById(GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]));
        if(!(rows[i]["Column_x0020_1"] === ""))
            row.style.backgroundColor = '#3ea866';
    }
    ctx.skipNextAnimation = true;
}
```

Is there any way to keep the formatting and still keep the animation?

Answer (score 1):

Learned something new today from your question..

`OnPostRender` is getting executed only on page load. From this [link](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2014/js-link-highlighting-a-row-with-csr/#comment-136) it seems we can hook the filter/sorting event via `_spBodyOnHashChange`

```
_spBodyOnHashChange = function({ 
    postRenderHandler(ctx);
    ajaxNavigate._raiseNavigate(ajaxNavigate);
}
```